# What vbcode should I use to restart my application but will show its second form instead of the first form

Tags: database

My form1 is login. I want my program to restart but form2 will show instead of the first form. what is the code for that? Pls help

Comment: Your question is completely unclear. What forms? Which database?

Comment: I have 2forms, form1 is login form form2 is registration form. I used application.restart() to restart my program and it restarted and login showed first. But I need form2 to show first when I restart my program. I'm using accessdatabase.

Answer (score 0):

Consider hiding the login form instead of restarting the whole app. Check the visibility property of your forms. This can be changed programatically.

Comment: I did. but I really need to restart my program. Because if I restart it, iget the right output. But hope not to login in form1.